# Model for "$\kappa$ limit cardinal iff $2^\kappa$ limit cardinal"

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, cardinal-arithmetic

Is there a model of ${\sf (ZFC)}$ such that in the model we have that $\kappa$ is a limit cardinal if and only if $2^\kappa$ is a limit cardinal?

Comment: A related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226887/when-can-power-sets-be-limit-cardinals

Comment: Actually, [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226887/when-can-power-sets-be-limit-cardinals#comment560225_226892) to the answer is exactly the present question.

Comment: This is definitely not an easy question - indeed, a model like this would violate the [singular cardinal hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_cardinals_hypothesis), and negation of SCH has quite high consistency strength.

Comment: @Wojowu "definitely not easy" if the answer is "yes".   But it is conceivable that there is an easy "no"...

Comment: @Goldstern I wouldn't expect an easy "no" either personally, seeing how difficult it is to study the continuum function at singular cardinals whatsoever (and also because I would expect the answer to be yes :P )