Is "$2^{|X|} = \aleph_{|X|^+}$ for all infinite sets $X$" consistent with ZFC?
Is the statement "$2^{|X|} = \aleph_{|X|^+}$ for all infinite sets $X$" consistent with ZFC?
For a point of reference, see Can the continuum be a singular cardinal?

If by $|X|^+$ you meant the successor ordinal of $|X|$, I believe this is true in Easton’s model that satisfies $2^\kappa = \aleph_{\kappa+1}$ for all regular cardinals $\kappa$, since in that model $2^\kappa$ for a singular $\kappa$ is the minimal cardinal $\lambda$ s.t. $\lambda \geq \aleph_{\eta+1}$ for all cardinal $\eta < \kappa$ and $\text{cf}(\lambda) > \kappa$, which is exactly $\aleph_{\kappa+1}$.

Sorry for the ambiguity in notation.  I was using $|X|^+$ to refer to the cardinal successor to $|X|$.

@David: The use of $\alpha^+$ as the successor ordinal in some texts which present only the very basic introduction to set theory is somehow understandable (since $x\cup{x}$ is, in a good sense, a successor of $x$ as a set). But the notation is unambiguously used in set theory to mean the cardinal successor. Indeed, one of the few cases of notation meaning "pretty much just the one thing" that I can think of in set theory.

Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/q/368387/7206 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/138308/7206 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/226887/7206 which might have something of an answer to your actual question.

@AsafKaragila I know. I use $^+$ to denote cardinal successor and $+ 1$ to denote ordinal successor as well. (I even wrote $\kappa + 1$ in my comment.) I simply don’t know the answer to the question if $^+$ meant cardinal successor, but I do know the answer if it’s replaced by ordinal successor, so I only wrote a comment (instead of an answer), just in case the OP used $^+$ in a nonstandard way. That’s not the case, as OP has indicated now, but I think it’s still reasonable to keep the comment given its relevance to the question, especially the discussion below Joel’s answer.

This is not a full answer, but let me mention that your hypothesis has large cardinal strength, because it implies the failure of the singular cardinals hypothesis.
Assume $2^\kappa=\aleph_{\kappa^+}$ for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$. (I am taking your $|X|^+$ to refer to the cardinal successor.) Let $\kappa$ be a singular strong limit cardinal. By your hypothesis, we have $2^\kappa=\aleph_{\kappa^+}$, but this is strictly bigger than $\kappa^+$, since successor cardinals are never $\aleph$-fixed points, and so SCH fails in every instance.
The failure of SCH has the large cardinal strength of a measurable cardinal $\kappa$ of Mitchell rank $\kappa^{++}$.
Meanwhile, if you assert your property $2^{\kappa}=\aleph_{\kappa^+}$ only for regular cardinals $\kappa$, then this is equiconsistent with ZFC by Easton's theorem.

Thank you for your answer.  If we assume that my statement is true just for regular cardinals, then what does Easton's model say $2^\kappa$ is for singular cardinals $\kappa$?

That is what David Gao's comment is about on the main question.

Sure.  I thought it might reduce to a simpler description in this particular case. I'll think about it some more.

According to what he says, it seems that we will have $2^\kappa=\aleph_{\kappa+1}$ for singular infinite cardinals $\kappa$ in the relevant Easton model, since such a cardinal is always a limit cardinal, and so $2^\lambda$ for regular $\lambda<\kappa$ will be $\aleph_{\lambda^+}<\aleph_\kappa$, meaning that $2^{<\kappa}=\aleph_\kappa$ and so $2^\kappa$ is $\aleph_{\kappa+1}$ as he explains.
